# Substitute the \infty provided by the eulervm package

Tags: fonts, math-mode, eulervm

How can I substitute the `\infty` of the `eulervm` package with the `\infty` at the left (that in text mode) in this [PDF](http://milde.users.sourceforge.net/LUCR/Math/mathpackages/fourier-symbols.pdf)? (to find it easily, please use the `ctrl+f` combination and then type `\infty`)

```
\documentclass{book}

\RequirePackage[%
               nomath,%
               nott,%
%              nosf,%
               noamsmath,%
               notextcomp,%
               oldstylenums%
               ]{kpfonts}

\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}


\begin{document}

\[
\mathcal{L}[f(t)](s)=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)e^{-st}dt
\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: What has `\infty` that doesn't please you?

Comment: @egreg I think that the \infty provided by the eulervm is taken from the CM fonts; in fact if you look at it, you can see that it does not fit very well the shapes of the eulervm package fonts.

Comment: The glyph is taken from the font `euex10` which looks like Euler to me.

Answer (score 8):

If I ask

```
\show\infty
```

I get

```
\infty=\mathchar"399
```

which means that the glyph is taken from font family 3, slot `0x99`. The font in family 3 is `U/zeuex/m/n` that corresponds to `zeuex10`; this is the relevant part in `uzeuex.fd`:

```
\DeclareFontShape{U}{zeuex}{m}{n}{
   <-> \zeu@@Scale zeuex10
}{}
```

Now, if I do

```
vptovf zeuex10
```

and look for character `O 231` (octal 231 is hexadecimal 99), I see

```
(CHARACTER O 231
   (CHARWD R 1.0)
   (CHARHT R 0.431)
   (MAP
      (SELECTFONT D 1)
      (SETCHAR O 61)
      )
   )
```

which means that this glyph is actually taken from the font number allocated as number 1 in this virtual font, using the slot "octal 61". So what's font 1? It's defined by

```
(MAPFONT D 1
   (FONTNAME euex10)
   (FONTCHECKSUM O 14201660461)
   (FONTAT R 1.0)
   (FONTDSIZE R 10.0)
   )
```

which points to `euex10`, which is the Euler Extension font. So the conclusion is that the glyph for `\infty` is exactly what the Euler font designs it to be.